# Power BI show date ranges in column heading in correct order

Tags: powerbi

So I have a report that is a rolling 12 month sales report.  The numbers are grouped by fiscal month, that doesn't necessarily align with the calendar month.  I am displaying the date ranges in the column heading and I am wondering if there is a way to display the columns in correct chronological order.

[image: report headings]

Comment: Are those ranges a text field in some table?

Comment: @AlexisOlson yes they are.  There is a join to the table on the back end that links the date to it's fiscal period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended getting the year and followed by the fiscal period (1,2,3) etc.  I put a zero in front of the single digit numbers